# Error in incrementing a number: Android

Tags: android

```
int imageNum =0; 
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera mCamera) {

    String Name = PatientInfo.getText().toString();
    String Age =  PatientAge.getText().toString();
    String Id = PatientId.getText().toString();

    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());

    Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum)+".jpg";
    File imagesFolders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Name + Age + gender +Id);

    imagesFolders.mkdirs();
    File output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);

    while (output.exists()) {
        imageNum++;
        Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);
    }

    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    OutputStream imageFileOS;

    try { 
        imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
        imageFileOS.write(data);
        imageFileOS.flush();
        imageFileOS.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
    }

    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
```

This is a part of my code. I am trying to save an image in a folder with its file name with an incrementation. Each time I click, an image is saved in a folder with RAW16-01-1405-20-22_img_0. *img* has to increase each time I take the picture. Can anyone help? Where's the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the snippet,

```
  while (output.exists()){
    imageNum++;
    Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg";
    output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);
 }
```

Change it like

```
while (output.exists()){
    imageNum++;
    Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg";

 }
imageNum++;
Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg";
output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the loop would run for infinity then, since if output.exists is true, it will never change within the loop causing it to run forever.

Comment: you are right. I changed the snippet. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @blackbelt i tried it but what nicklas said is creating a problem...its creating a infinty loop....hw can i change it

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what your problem is exactly but you should persist the imageNum counter since it will be reset to 0 as soon as a new instance is created of the class, which will happen sooner or later.

Use **SharedPreferences** or similar to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (output.exists()){
            imageNum++;
            Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);
        }
Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);
```

While loop ends with Rname and output having values for the last existing file. you need to give values for the new one as well.

Comment: i tried this its nt wrking still _img_0 is displayed in every imagefile name

Comment: Rname = "Raw"+s.toString() + "_img_"+ String.valueOf(imageNum) +".jpg"; here "s" which is tym component it must be changing

Comment: so the file name has changed now if you do output.exists() it will always return false because now change name file does not exist.